# MS VISIO, how do you resize a shape and maintain it's "inner proportions" (i.e. without garbling the shape)

Tags: visio

Hopefully there is an easy answer that I can't find right now..

Problem:

Let's look at **Arrow Shapes** --> **Quad Arrow**

This shape has several controls that let you tweak it's internal proportions.
[image]

But if you try to re-size the whole shape..  those internal proportions just go all over the place:

[image]

That's not the desired outcome!
No combination of SHIFT ALT CTRL seems to prevent that.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know how to solve this issue?

*It's not a bug it's a feature* :) [©](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_(engineering)#%22It%27s_not_a_bug,_it%27s_a_feature%22)

You can change this shape's shapesheet, where you change rows in [Geometry section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/geometry-section) from absolute to relative values (from [MoveTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/moveto-row-geometry-section)/[LineTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/lineto-row-geometry-section) to [RelMoveTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/relmoveto-row-geometry-section)/[RelLineTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/rellineto-row-geometry-section)).
After this you must delete [Controls section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/controls-section).

You can use this simple macro for do all these steps at a moment.

```
Sub QuadArrowFix()
Dim sh As Shape ' active shape
Dim Se As Section ' geometry section
Set sh = ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem ' 1st selected shape
Set Se = sh.Section(visSectionFirstComponent) ' definegeometry section
sh.RowType(visSectionFirstComponent, 1) = visTagRelMoveTo ' change to RelMoveTo
For i = 2 To Se.Count - 1
sh.RowType(visSectionFirstComponent, i) = visTagRelLineTo ' change to RelLineTo
Next
sh.DeleteSection visSectionControls ' delete ControlsPts section
set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you kind stranger.     Your macro does in-fact make this problem go away!    I'm a little baffled that THIS is what it takes, but who am I to tell MicroSoft what makes sense